# What is causing the "Unable to find any valuable Window provider" error in my Python App that is using the kivy library

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to build an Android app using the kivy library. When I installed kivy using pip, I had no issues, but when I tried to build a basic App, I get this Error:

```
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _window_sdl2: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\Fabian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    mod = importlib.__import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1109, in __import__
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Fabian\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 28, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

The app I built looks like this:

```
import kivy

kivy.require("2.2.0") # My version of kivy, It also doesn't work if I remove this statement

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Hello, Kivy!')

TestApp = MyApp()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp.run()
```

I have tried running all these pip lines:
`python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew;`  python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2`

but nothing worked.

I have also already tried installing sdl2 manually, and also reinstalling the kivy package with pip, but nothing fixed the issue. Ive also checked if kivy was in my Pycharm interpreter but it also was.
What should I do to resolve the Issue?

Comment: I now got it to work myself, All i had to do was downgrade my python version from 3.9 to 3.6.0 . Hope this helps anybody that was facing the same issue